# Displaying Top 10 songs (Need help organizing the songs)

Tags: java, count

I am currently making a Jukebox style project. One thing the jukebox can do is display the top 10 songs(Or the the 10 songs that have been played the most). At the minute when a song is played in increments a count, however this count will increment for every song no matter what one is selected. So according to my program, when one song is played, they are all played.
Below I have code for a playTrack() method, a DisplayTop10() method and boolean play method.

```
private static void playATrack() {
        try {
            System.out.println("We have the following tracks:");
            String firstSong = jukebox.allTracks.get(0).getTitle();
            songs.add(firstSong);

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                System.out.println(SPACES + (index + 1) + ". " + jukebox.allTracks.get(index).getTitle());
            }

            System.out.println("Select a track to play: ");
            int songNumber = input.nextInt() - 1;
            input.nextLine();

            AudioTrack tk = jukebox.allTracks.get(songNumber);
            if (myJukebox.playTrack(tk) == false) {
                System.out.println(jukebox.allTracks.get(songNumber).getTitle() + " can not be played.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Now playing: " + jukebox.allTracks.get(songNumber).getTitle());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nplease select a valid song number.");
        }

    }

public static void displayTop10() {
        
        for (int index= 0; index < ConsleApplication.count; index++) {
            System.out.println(jukebox.allTracks.get(index).getTitle() + "---- Times played: " + myAudioPlayer.getTimesPlayed());
            }
        
        AudioTrack temp;
        if (jukebox.allTracks.size() > 1)
        {
            for ( int x = 0; x < jukebox.allTracks.size(); x++)
            {
                for (int i= 0; i < jukebox.allTracks.size()-i; i++) {
                    if (jukebox.allTracks.get(i) == (jukebox.allTracks.get(i+1)))
                    {
                        temp = jukebox.allTracks.get(i);
                        jukebox.allTracks.set(i, jukebox.allTracks.get(i + 1));
                        jukebox.allTracks.set(i + 1, temp);
}       
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }

public boolean play(AudioTrack tk) {
        if (tk.getEncoding().equalsIgnoreCase("mp3") || tk.getEncoding().equalsIgnoreCase("wav")){
            timesPlayed++;
            }
        return true;
        
    }
```

The last method there is in another class than the other two methods. I know there may be easier ways but I am sticking to a strict UML design. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you most likely would want to store to count to each song, or create a `Map<AudioTrack, Integer> playCountByTrack` and manage that to track individual play count. It would be easier to find top ten counts if you opt for the `Map` approach.

Comment: Thanks, I've never used a map but Ill certainly give it a go!

Comment: Yes, because you can get all entries and sort that by value, and then you can get the top ten entries and extract the relevant tracks.